# VS 2012 not using the dependencies downloaded by NuGet

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

I checkout a solution from a repo which is not owned by. The solution and/or the projects are not developed by me either. I follow this guide from [here](http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/1879). This is the summary:

> What worked finally was to
>
> check Tools|Options|package manager|Package restore right-click the
>   solution and "enable package restore" right-click a project in the
>   solution and "Manage nuget packages". Then you will finally get a bar
>   across the top of this UI with a message that some packages are
>   missing, click to get them. Clicking this button gets the packages.

So, I click on restore and NuGet seems to download the packages. However, when I try to build the project, it still complains that the dependencies are missing. I look at the packages folder in the solution folder and see all the necessary dependencies. But, for some reason the project is not correctly linking to it.

In other words, Solution/packages exists with all the libs but when I try to build the solution and/or project, I get a build fail. Does anyone know what is going on?

Thanks.

EDIT: For clarification, under warnings, I get

> Warning   18  The referenced component 'Microsoft.Practices.Unity' could
>   not be found.     BlueFin

EDIT 2: For another clarification, if I add existing references and go to the packages folder packages/lib/thefile.dll, it will compile properly and work. The question is, nuget should be doing this automatically for me right?

Comment: Under the `References`don't you see any small warnings?

Comment: Yup. They all have yellow warning signs next to it. When I look at the path, it is empty so the project is definitely not referencing the dependencies correctly. The question is how do I get to link correct? I'm new to vs 2012 and nuget

Comment: When you say `Solution/packages exists with all the libs`, can you link the libs in your `References`?

Comment: So, yea if I add existing reference and link the dll in the packages folder, then the errors go away but I shouldn't have to do that right? Shouldn't nuget handle that automatically?

Comment: If your `.sln` file references the dependencies with a relative path then you shouldn't have the problem.